# How can I synchronize wordpress users with firebase ones in python?

Tags: python, wordpress, firebase, hash, passwords

I would like that every time a user changes the password, it is also changed on firebase. The main problem is that the passwords taken from the wordpress database are hashed, while the auth.update_users command takes the raw password.
Obviously I'm not aware of the password in raw format...
What can I do?

i had try it:

```
...
users = auth.get_user_by_email('user1@gmail.com')
print('Successfully email fetched user data: {0}'.format(users.uid))
user = auth.update_user(
    uid=users.uid,
    password='$P$BOCNIc5Nw1e9fwm8HaLBChsd7eE4Hh1'
    )
print('Sucessfully updated user: {0}'.format(user.uid))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can reasonably do here with the hash. The whole purpose of storing hashes (and hopefully salts) is to make it unfeasible to brute force revert password hashes to their cleartext password. If you could do that, so could any malicious user that gets access to the database of hashes.

If you want to send the cleartext password to two providers, you'll have to capture it at the source (so when the user enters it in the web app) and then send it to both providers.

Comment: I have many users already registered on wordpress. And I wish they can log into a new app on firebase with the same credentials. I have no way to import them?? And if they then change password from wordpress to make sure that it syncs to firebase?

Comment: The Firebase CLI has an `auth:import` option, that allows you to import users with existing hashes. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#auth-import

Comment: @Player I have a plugin that can transfer WP users to Firebase. You can check it out here https://firebase-wordpress-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/firebase-users.html